# How to query data in dynamic table and column in HQL?

Tags: hive, hiveql

In our product, we have a wired scenario.

The backend service output the a HDFS as following.

```
|table_name| table_column| dimension|
|----|-----|----|
| A  | A1  | dimension1|
| B  | B1 | dimension2|
| C  | C2 | dimension3 |
```

It means that we need create a table named dimension with dimension1, dimension2 and dimension3 column,

The dimension1 value is from A1 column of A table , dimension2 is from B1 column of B column and dimension3 is from C2 column of C table.

Anyone know how to archieve that?

Comment: what would be join conditions of tables A,B,C ? You can use this `create table new_table as select A.A1 dimension1, B.B1 dimension2, C.C2 dimension3 from A,B,C where A.id = B.id and A.id = C.id ` I Assumed `id` column can be used to join these tables.

Comment: @KoushikRoy  The key problem is not the join conditions. The problem is the table name  and the column is dynamic. The dimension1 is from A.A1 today and it will be A.A2 for tomorrow.

Comment: i understand. you may need to use some programming language like python to prepare the SQL because you have everything dynamic, you dont have join condition in the table and first of all sql has to be formed from the table and then fire it to extract data.